# STDC14 connector pinout for ST-Link V3 for SWD debugging

Tags: stm32, st-link

I have a quick question:

In the ST-Link V3 datasheet the pinout of the STDC14 connector is mentioned as follows:

[image: Pinout]

I have a question regarding:

1. Pin 3: Should I connect the 3.3V signal from the target power supply? As far as I know, this is not for powering, but rather for setting the correct reference voltage, therefore connecting it is important;
2. Pin 11: I've seen designs which connect this pin directly to ground and ones with a 100Ω resistor to ground, what is the correct or "more" common thing to do?
3. Pin 13 and 14: Is this the interface for the USART connection, so that USART_RX from the uC is connected to pin 13 and USART_TX vice versa? Theoretically, could I leave the pins unwired if I am only interested in SWD debugging or is there any other benefit to it I am not recognising currently?

Comment: What is your target board and the logic Voltage levels? At this point is sound almost like your asking about using 6 PIN SWD connection setup verse 10 Pin ARM setup.

Comment: The `T_` prefix presumably means "Target" (meaning the device being programmed/debugged). For example, `T_XYZ` would refer to signal `XYZ` from the target board on the ST-LINK as this could help avoid ambiguity if there were another `XYZ` signal on that board.

Answer (score 2):

This question is similar to [one posted on ST's community discussion forum](https://community.st.com/s/question/0D53W00000q5NvuSAE/debugging-probe-stlink-v3-gnd-detect-input-signal-what-is-the-minimal-set-of-connections-essential-what-about-vcc-input). A good way to verify that what you're doing is OK is to compare it with a known-good reference board, such as one of ST's [NUCLEO offerings](https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/stm32-nucleo-boards.html).

For example, the [NUCLEO-G474's user manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/um2505-stm32g4-nucleo64-boards-mb1367-stmicroelectronics.pdf) includes Table 14 on page 28 (like OP but with slightly more helpful descriptions), and if you click on the ["CAD Resources" tab](https://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/evaluation-tools/product-evaluation-tools/mcu-mpu-eval-tools/stm32-mcu-mpu-eval-tools/stm32-nucleo-boards/nucleo-g474re.html#cad-resources) of the NUCLEO/DK/eval board page you'll often find complete board design & manufacturing files as well as schematic. In this case you can peek at [the schematic](https://www.st.com/resource/en/schematic_pack/mb1367-g474re-c05_schematic.pdf) and see how CN4 is connected.

[image: CN4 pinout on NUCLEO-G474 schematic]

1. Yes, you should connect pin 3 to the MCU's VCC/VDD/V+ supply.
2. I would include 100ohm resistor as ST's reference boards do. However, I do not think it matters unless your (target) MCU needs to detect the presence of the ST-LINK debugger hardware. If you look at note 6 of the table referenced it says, "Tied to GND by STLINK-V3SET firmware; may be used by the target for detection of the tool." Perhaps it is intended to be pulled up to T_VCC with weak pull-up resistor for that case?
3. You can leave them unwired if you don't care about the VCP (virtual COM port) functionality. However, I would double check whether Rx/Tx needs to be flipped or not. The [STLink-MINIE](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stlink-v3minie.html#documentation) user manual section 6.3 / Table 4 shows T_VCP_TX as an input and T_VCP_RX as an output.

[image: VCP Rx/Tx connections]